# Python shelve not saving nested keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, shelve

I am using the `shelve` module to save some Python objects (strings in the example).

When I am trying to save an object as a nested key, then it is not being saved.

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.id = ID

    def save_to_shelf(self):
        with shelve.open('shelf') as shelf:
           if not shelf.get('users'):
                shelf['users'] = {}

            print(shelf['users'])
            try:
                shelf['users'][self.id] = "hello"
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            print('saved')
            print(shelf['users'])

car = Car(123)
car.save_to_shelf()
```

**The code should print:**

```
{}
saved
{123: hello}
```

**But instead it prints:**

```
{}
saved
{}
```

Meaning that it is not getting saved

If I print the value of the key, it gives `KeyError`

```
shelf['users'][self.id] = "hello"
print(shelf['users'][self.id])
```

**Error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Python practice/Shelll/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    car.save_to_shelf()
  File "P:/Python practice/Shelll\db.py", line 20, in save_to_shelf
    print(shelf['users'][self.id])
KeyError: '123'
```

**I am able to save it if I do the following while saving**
Instead of

```py
with shelve.open('shelf') as shelf:
    shelf['users'][self.id] = "hello"
```

This works

```py
with shelve.open('shelf') as shelf:
    USERS = shelf['users']
    USERS[self.id] = self.id
    shelf['users'] = USERS
# or this works
# with shelve.open('shelf') as shelf:
#     shelf['users'] = {self.id:"hello"}
```

I want to understand the reason behind this. As far as I know, `shelve` objects work as a dictionary. So the way I was saving earlier should work but does not.

Comment: Because `shelf` is a shelf, `shelf['users']` is a `dict`. You only add to your shelf here: `shelf['users'] = {}`... it will always be and empty dict. `shelf['users'][self.id] = "hello"` does not assign to a a shelf, it *retrieves* from a shelf, `shelf['users']`, which returns a new dictionary object, deserialized from the underlying pickle, then you assign to that `dict`, `shelf['users'][self.id] = "hello"`. But that dict is discarded immediately, you don't keep any references to it around, and even if you did, it wouldn't affect the shelf.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think this answers my query. I had been spending my days trying to figure out what was I doing wrong. Understood the underlying issue now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was worried it still wasn't clear. But I'm glad that clarifies for you.